# Is there anything a Green Lantern ring can't create?

Tags: dc, green-lantern

I know it's limited by the user's willpower and imagination, but is there anything the rings truly can't create?

Comment: Let me guess ... Another ring?

Comment: No, they can make those. Hal Jordan did it in Green Lantern vol. 3 issue 106. Kyle used it to kind of (unsuccessfully) restart the Corps.

Comment: Let me try again ! A whole galaxy?

Comment: They can't create love.

Comment: Anything yellow.

Comment: They can't create something not green. What do I win?

Comment: I don't think we've seen a Green Lantern try and fail to create anything due a limitation of *the ring*. The only limitation of this kind that I can speculate is creating a functional, different corps', ring.

Comment: @cde Actually, John Stewart pulled off non-green constructs by creating them while flying at near-light speed, causing a color shift. Ridiculous physics, I suppose, but cannon at one time.

Comment: I'd be interested in seeing that. Issue?

Comment: Aside from that, I think I remember a scene or cap of a Lantern, maybe Guy, where the ring says that the users will power is exceeding the rings capability, with green sparks shooting out of the ring.

Comment: @cde It's been a long time. I would put it at roughly post-Crisis / pre-Zero Hour. Something I don't have electronically and would have to spend hours digging through my disorganized collection to locate. If noone comes up with it by the time I am freer, I will attempt Google-fu.

Comment: a good movie about himself.

Comment: @phantom42 oh man, buuuuuuuurn.

Comment: @cde - the color shift was in Ganthet's Tale.

Comment: @SplittingAdam Did the alternate universe Hal Jordan make rings for the other 'lanterns' when training in the Phantom Zone in "Superman:Red Son"?

Comment: @CBredlow I can't recall if they explained how the other Lanterns got their rings, but I remember Luthor was tinkering with the ring they found and I'd assume they came from said tinkering.

Comment: Rainbows are the best example I can think of.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As far as physical constructs go, it would appear that the ring is limited only by the wielder's imagination and willpower. **The one exception to this would appear to be life.** A Green Lantern can create something closely approximating a living being (as seen in [**Green Lantern Vol. 3 #48**](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Green_Lantern_Vol_3_48)), but actual life is beyond the ability of a ring to create. It should be noted, however, that Hal Jordan thought the Central Battery on Oa contained enough power to do so:

[image]

That being said, the Green Lantern ring is capable of creating anything from microscopic nanites to entire planets. Even the color of said constructs is not limited to green. In one case ([**Green Lantern: Ganthet's Tale**](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Green_Lantern:_Ganthet's_Tale)), Hal Jordan was able to shift the color of his ring's construct to yellow:

[image]

Green Lanterns have also been able to create semi-permanent constructs that last long after they leave, as well as influence life on a genetic level (both seen during the [Rann-Thanagar War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rann%E2%80%93Thanagar_War)). And, of course, any Green Lantern with the sufficient knowledge can create additional Green Lantern rings as needed, although this is rarely done.

[image]

Comment: didn't Hal recreate his home city at one point? I don't remember if these people were just a simulation or actually "alive"

Comment: @Petersaber they weren't actually alive, but close. His inability to do so for real was what prompted him to head for Oa - he intended to ask the Guardians for more power so that he could make the city & people real. Obviously, they refused.